# Sphinx/PlantUML error when trying to create DOCX

Tags: python-sphinx, docx, plantuml

Fedora Box:

I have worked with Sphinx and PlantUML the past few months and have gotten pretty familiar with it.  Specifically getting it to build via HTML, PDF, and DOCX. But I am running into an issue that I hope you all can help me out with.

Currently, if I use PlantUML to render an image via the .jar file (and just include this new image as a link in the .rst document), Sphinx has no problem building up this project. HTML, PDF, DOCX, doesn't matter. Document is created, image is shown.

But if I install the PlantUML plugin ([sphinxcontrib-plantuml-0.21.tar.gz][1]), and put the same code (minus @start/end) in the .rst document, Sphinx will only build it via HTML. It looks perfect there. But if I build via DOCX, I get a PlantUML error. The document will build, the DOCX file is there, but no pictures are.

Does anyone else have experience with Sphinx, PlantUML plugin, and trying to get it to render DOCX?

Error messages if building via DOCX (`make docx`with https://pypi.org/project/docxbuilder/):

> Warning: Ignore unknown node plantuml

Comment: You wrote: "I get a red PlantUML error." how does this error read?

Comment: Hey peeps! I answered your questions in the OP, I edited it. Short answer is Yes, and I wrote the errors

Comment: @mzjn yes, I am using that ext. Updated OP

Comment: sounds good man, i'll create a new thread for PDF issues

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get DOCX to work by following the instructions at ([this site](https://docxbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/third_party_extensions.html)), copy the below into your Conf.py file.

```
# Define setup function in conf.py
def setup(app):
    # Define visit method for plantuml node generated by sphinxcontrib.plantuml
    # https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-plantuml/
    def docx_visit_plantuml(self, node):
        def get_filepath(self, node):
            from sphinxcontrib import plantuml
            _, filepath = plantuml.render_plantuml(self, node, 'png')
            return filepath
        alt = node.get('alt', (node['uml'], None))
        # Docxbuilder provides useful methods. See Docxbuilder API reference.
        self.visit_image_node(node, alt, get_filepath)
    # Add the visit method to Docxbuilder
    import docxbuilder
    translator = docxbuilder.DocxBuilder.default_translator_class
    setattr(translator, 'visit_plantuml', docx_visit_plantuml)
```